# How do I use the built in body parser of express js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I am following a ReactJS tutorial created 2-4 years ago. The tutorial is adapting to a MVC pattern. The request starts on `server.js` then it goes to the `routes` file. The routes will then forward it to the `controller` to give any response accordingly.

You can view the basic code below.

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const morgan = require('morgan')
const cors = require('cors')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
require('dotenv').config()

const app = express()

// connect to db
mongoose
    // connection code
  })
  .then(() => console.log('DB connected'))
  .catch(err => console.log('DB CONNECTION ERROR: ', err))

// import routes
const authRoutes = require('./routes/auth')

// middleware
app.use('/api', authRoutes)

// app midllewares
app.use(morgan('dev'))
app.use(express.json()) // body-parser is now deprecated as of Express 4.16+
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

const port = process.env.PORT || 8000
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`API is running on port ${port} - ${process.env.NODE_ENV}`)
})
```

**/routes/auth.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

// import controller
const {signup} = require('../controllers/auth')

router.post('/signup', signup);

module.exports = router; // {}
```

**/controllers/auth.js**

```
const express = require('express')

exports.signup = (req, res) => {
  console.log('REQ BODY ON SIGNUP', req.body); // shows the posted data on terminal
  res.json({
    data: 'you hit signup endpoint'
  });
```

}

**package.json**

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@sendgrid/mail": "^7.7.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "express-jwt": "^8.4.1",
    "express-validator": "^6.15.0",
    "google-auth-library": "^8.7.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.0",
    "mongoose": "^7.0.3",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.22"
  }
}
```

I then use postman to send data using `POST` method to `http://localhost:8000/api/signup`

**Headers**

```
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
```

**Raw JSON**

```
{
    "name": "John",
    "email": "johndoe@gmail.com",
    "password": "mmmmm"
}
```

**Problem:** The problem I am currently facing is that I am seeing `req.body` as `undefined` in the terminal when I send the POST data via postman. Please see the terminal output below.

```
$ npm start

> mern-auth-server@1.0.0 start
> nodemon server.js

[nodemon] 2.0.22
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
API is running on port 8000 - development
DB connected
REQ BODY ON SIGNUP undefined
```

I am using express for parsing since body-parser got deprecated since version 4.16.0 or later of express.

Do you guys know how can I solve this? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: move the app middlewares up above routes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of middleware registrations also matter. The JSON request body parsing should happen before hitting the routes since the routes need the parsed body. So need to move up the parsing middleware before attaching the routes.

```js
// import routes
const authRoutes = require('./routes/auth')

// app midllewares
app.use(morgan('dev'))
app.use(express.json()) // body-parser is now deprecated as of Express 4.16+
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

// middleware
app.use('/api', authRoutes)
```

Comment: Your answer worked. I just knew this now that the order of middleware registrations matter. Thank you very much

Comment: @redshot good to hear it works